# How to apply discriminating union technique to function signatures?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, discriminated-union

I want to apply discriminating union technique to function signatures.

Code example

```
type fun1 = (opts: {type: 'a', value: string}) => string;
type fun2 = (opts: {type: 'b', value: number}) => number;

type anyFun = fun1 | fun2;

class Clazz {
  innerMethod<T extends anyFun>(opts: Parameters<T>[0]): ReturnType<T> {
    return 123 as ReturnType<T>;
  }

  otherMethod() {
    // Case 1 - FAILED
    // expected result type: string
    // actual result type: string | number
    const result1 = this.innerMethod({type: 'a', value: 'str'});

    // Case 2 - OK
    // expected result type = actual type = string
    const result2 = this.innerMethod<fun1>({type: 'a', value: 'str'});

    // Case 3 - OK
    // TS error that fun2 is incompatible with type: 'a'
    const result3 = this.innerMethod<fun2>({type: 'a', value: 'str'});
  }
}
```

I want write code in case 1 manner without explicit type declaration but TypeScript type inferring returns wrong type in this case.

How is it possible to write code in this manner using function signatures? Or the only way is changing function signature types?

**UPD.** A bit more information what problem I want to solve.

I have a facade which wraps set of services.

Each service has API and part of this API are synchronous getters.

Service may request information from other service via getter.

Getter may be described as function signature.

I want to use this signature in two places:

1. Service which implements getter and it works good.
2. Service which calls getter and here I got problem with discriminating union.

Code:

```
type Fork = number;
type Spoon = string;

type GetFork = (arg: {type: 'fork', id: number}) => Fork;
type GetSpoon = (arg: {type: 'spoon', id: number}) => Spoon;

interface Facade {

  constructor(services: AbstractService[]);

  // routes request to service which can execute getter
  get(request): any;
}

class AbstractService<NeedGetters extends (arg: any) => any = never> {
  facade!: Facade;

  init(facade: Facade) {
    this.facade = facade;
  }

  getFromFacade<T extends NeedGetters>(opts: Parameters<T>[0]): ReturnType<T> {
    return this.facade.get(opts);
  }
}
interface ForksService extends AbstractService {
  getFork({type}: Parameters<GetFork>[0]): ReturnType<GetFork>;
}

interface SpoonsService extends AbstractService {
  getSpoon({type}: Parameters<GetSpoon>[0]): ReturnType<GetSpoon>;
}

class StuffService extends AbstractService<GetFork | GetSpoon> {
  someMethod() {
    // TS infered type string | number
    const fork = this.getFromFacade({type: 'fork', id: 25});

    // TS infered type string | number
    const spoon = this.getFromFacade({type: 'spoon', id: 36});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is represented as function signatures when there doesn't seem to be a function of this type, but if I wanted to write a version of `innerMethod()` that allowed for type inference, I'd do something like this:

```
innerMethod<P extends Parameters<AnyFun>[0]>(
  opts: P
): ReturnType<Extract<AnyFun, (opts: P) => any>> {
  return 123 as any;
}
```

The problem with your version is that the compiler cannot reliably infer `T extends AnyFun` from a value of type `Parameters<T>[0]`.  The compiler does not know how to "reverse engineer" the right `T` type from that.  The most reliable form of type inference is to give the compiler a value of the type you want to infer, and then *calculate* other types from it.

In the above, the type `P` is the type of the `opts` parameter passed in.  We are [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) it to `Parameters<AnyFun>[0]`, which is

```
{
    type: "a";
    value: string;
} | {
    type: "b";
    value: number;
}
```

One we have `P`, we can use [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to get the member of `AnyFun` whose first parameter is of type `P`, and then use [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) on *that*.  You can see that it works now:

```
otherMethod() {
  const result1 = this.innerMethod({ type: 'a', value: 'str' }); // string
  result1.toUpperCase(); // okay
}
```

---

But as I said, it seems strange to me to represent such a type mapping in terms of functions.  In the absence of extenuating information about your use case, I'd be inclined to rewrite your code like this:

```
type IOMapping = { a: string, b: number }

innerMethod<K extends keyof IOMapping>(
  opts: { type: K, value: IOMapping[K] }
): IOMapping[K] {
  return 123 as any;
}
```

which behaves similarly in terms of type inference, but requires significantly less type manipulation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1&ts=4.3.2&strict=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUPkkgC4CeMyAYgK7ACMSAvEgBQD2MJUAXHqRQh8A5CGEAaJADdMNIUigkATgEtgAcyQBfAJTMAfAuVr1AbiIDKSWsABMzNp259cl+cIBGE6bPnAaYB4QStp6TIb+gcHmFuRWAILAZDYONowAPtZ0tjHE8BggUFBIAMIFWDgExMRqwMEAshAkABbsACYAPAAKSBAAHiQQwG3FXSBK4E3BUB2JyXT6ANoADAC6+qwW1UhOvEhdW0g6fABKTTRKwAAqgh0AogMT8CSzSTaSHFx7XWGGIEn6QxVbZIJTnS5Iei2ADMSEKcKS5m2WkI23YLQaTVabVYemB23g7GAilB0BoGBIjBYLRUUAAdLVMS12qxXHF3GJJDIMHIRIolMJQqYkAB6EVGVQaQ7EMFQcmUukkdgAVRglCUJUKEFxwrFOwA1iAyIcUcQUfhzaBILAEMgABJgMB4VFuJAASQA8vUQGqTA5XCA+PyTJIPHxIkEQua8gUiqVypVDoylI1mZ0ANK9AZDEZIfUQMjsABm7q9PpgJg20p2Xxcbj46a5vj4nu9vo0i3Tq20h2OpbbFY7XedINJJAuwEhMLhxX+ZCR1Wj1XRzSZ2NxI5BhOJJFJcopVNIzVpDOAdRTWJZbMEIk5Ph57n5gt0uvFwalo9l8voipVauCmpQNqOivgaRomhY5paEAA)

Comment: I added more information about the problem I want to solve.

Comment: The first half of my answer translated to that code looks like [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7bRRw), which infers `fork` and `spoon` types as desired, I think.

Comment: I applied your fix and it solves my problem, thank you)